# Contact Form 7 + Configure SMTP: Sender email appearing as my own email

Tags: email, plugin-contact-form-7, smtp

I have Contact Form 7 and Configure SMTP installed on my website. When a user submits a message through the form, everything comes through fine but the sender email is never displayed. Instead, it is displayed as my own email so I have no clue who sent the message. It just shows up as "To: my email, From: my email".

Below are my settings for both CF7 and Configure SMTP. Are any of them wrong?

Contact Form 7
[image: CF7]

Configure SMTP
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, your Contact Form 7 and SMTP Configuration are correct so you are getting emails properly.

Now coming back to your question:

> it is displayed as my own email :

it is correct behavior because actually you are sending email to yourself :)

> the sender email is never displayed.

To view the persons name and email address (filled in the form), you will need to include in the message body as displayed in following screenshot:
[image: update settings in message body to display name and email address from the form]